# Post запрос, обработка ошибки 401

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, javascript

Делаю post запрос на свою страницу. При определенных данных, страница возвращает ошибку 401, 404 и другие. Как мне обработать полученную ошибку?

```
    jQuery.post('?r=stationery/stationeryRequest/RequestDone', 
        {
            id: ids,
            value: val,
            YII_CSRF_TOKEN: '<?php echo Yii::app()->request->csrfToken;?>'
        },
        function(data){
            data = parseJSON(data);
            ShowRequsetStatus(obj.parent(), data);
        }
    );
```

Как я понял при 401-ой в функцию `function(data)` он не зайдет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Собственно я сам разобрался. Переделал .post на .ajax там есть обработчик:

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "?r=stationery/stationeryRequest/RequestDone",
        data: {
            id: ids,
            value: val,
            YII_CSRF_TOKEN: '<?php echo Yii::app()->request->csrfToken;?>'
        },
        error: function(){
            ShowRequstStatus(obj.parent(), [ids, val, val]);
        },
        success: function(data){
            data = parseJSON(data);
            ShowRequstStatus(obj.parent(), data);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

> "401 Unautorized" Запрос требует
> аутентификации пользователя "404 Not
> Found" Запрашиваемый документ на
> сервере отсутствует

если такие ошибки возникают то тут изначально дело не в POST запросе а в адресе и доступу к этому адресу!

Comment: знаю, код 401 я сам генерирую, и хочу чтобы JS от них не вылетал, а обрабатывал их )